# how to check if value return in plpython query?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have this assignment in `plpythonu` in PostgreSQL function:

```
result=plpy.execute("select  value from table  where doctitle like '%%%s%%'"%projectname)
if result:
    final = result[0]["value"]
```

The query can return 1 text result or nothing.

The issue is that if the query returned nothing the if `result:` condition is still `true` (Cuz it contains the value column)... I want the assignment to `final` happen only if there is actual value in value column.  How do I check for that?

Comment: The cursor does not return the column header , but it does return an empty array ( list i think) so this will always be true. Use count len instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result object emulates a list or dictionary object. Check its length:

```
if len(result) > 0:
```

But your test should work as an empty list or dictionary evaluates as `False`:

```
create or replace function p()
returns boolean as $$

result = plpy.execute('select 1 as i where false')
if result: return True
else: return False

$$ language plpythonu;
```

Returns `false`:

```
select p();
 p 
---
 f
```

Pass the parameters to `execute` in instead of substitute yourself. Otherwise you will vulnerable to SQL injection:

```
query = """
    select value
    from table
    where doctitle like format('%%%s%%', $1)
"""
plan = plpy.prepare(query, ["text"])
result = plpy.execute(plan, [_text_parameter])
if result:
    final = result[0]["value"]
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython-database.html